# confusing in mysql database tables

Tags: php, mysql

i am bit confuse in to getting the result into the two tables, i know it is simple but not getting any clue..
here is my query the gives me the result, but when i am using the `group by` then it's just giving me the result of one line even the actual result in database is (300, 500) because i am fetching the result through the `lead_id` which is common in both tables..

```
SELECT inv.amount, crmd.computers, crmd.product_id, crmd.pc_opti
FROM invoice AS inv, lead_crm_data AS crmd
WHERE inv.lead_id = '310'
AND crmd.lead_id = '310'
GROUP BY inv.lead_id
```

here is the result of the given query..

```
amount  computers   product_id  pc_opti
300     2           7, 6            2
300     3           7, 6            3
540     2           7, 6            2
540     3           7, 6            3
```

result with **GROUP BY**

```
300     2           7, 6            2
```

**Desired REsult**

```
300     2           7, 6            2
540     3           7, 6            3
```

Comment: what are the fields that u used in group by condition?

Comment: @Til86 `lead_id` because lead id is the common field in both tables..

Comment: can you write your coding with group by command & the result u get

Comment: Are you sure you know what GROUP BY means? What exactly you want to achieve with this query?

Comment: Show us your desired result please...

Comment: @Marco i have updated the according to the comments plz let me know where i did the mistake

Comment: So... you're pretty much were after SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT inv.amount, crmd.computers, crmd.product_id, crmd.pc_opti
FROM invoice AS inv, lead_crm_data AS crmd
WHERE inv.lead_id = '310'
  AND crmd.lead_id = '310'
GROUP BY inv.amount
```

You could use a better (IMHO) syntax:

```
SELECT inv.amount, crmd.computers, crmd.product_id, crmd.pc_opti
FROM invoice AS inv INNER JOIN lead_crm_data AS crmd 
    ON inv.lead_id = crmd.lead_id 
   AND inv.lead_id = '310'
GROUP BY inv.amount
```

Comment: @jogesh_p: because lead_id is '310' already, so when you group you get only one record!! You want one different record for each "amount" when lead_id is 310... and so does my query :)

Comment: :) thanks a lot, i also tried with the `INNER JOIN` but never got the desired result,, +1 to clarifying and the alternative :)